# which address do I use to receive and which one to transact and sell/trade?

Tags: bitcoind, client

in localbitcoins we have address to receive bitcoins.

In Coinbase we can create multiple addresses for bitcoin.

Now which one do I use to receive and which one to transact and sell/trade?

because the address in localbitcoins is shown as invalid at some free bitcoin generation sites/ while the coinbase addresses work